# Exceptions.Job.ObjectModelValidationException when trying to set up Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-stream-analytics

I try to get into Microsoft Azure. For that i just set up the demo application described under

https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/

now i want to try out stream analytics, for that i configured an input, listening to the IoT Hub and an Output writing to a DB.

Whenever i start the Stream Analytics Job i got an error like that:

```
Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Unable to load type Microsoft.Streaming.StreamingExceptions.Exceptions.Job.ObjectModelValidationException required for deserialization.
```

Why is that? What did i miss here?

Answer (score 3):

A fix has been deployed to production. This happens when the query fails validation, instead of showing user the error message we end up showing the exception. Sorry for the inconvenience, please try again.

Comment: It seems that @ZhongChen is a Microsoft employee so this is an authoritative answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the actual response. Now i now where to head to for my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I selected a SQL Database as output for my job. I simply recreated the output and it started working. Make sure the alias you assign for your output match the one you indicated in your job query (INTO).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually the new error indicates, i tried to access an input column that does not exist... but how can i find out which data structure the IoT Hub Creates for the inputs?